# Unbounded linear operator for $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm trying to find a non-bounded operator in $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_2)$, that is, a function $T:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\nexists K > 0. |Tx| \le K \cdot ||x||_2$ where $||x||_2 = \sqrt{\int_{0}^1 |x(t)|^2 dt}$.

The derivative provided me with an example with the infinite norm and [these notes](https://www.impan.pl/~lpalmisano/fa2017/lecture4.pdf) suggests that the evaluationat zero could be a candidate. But still I cannot come up with an example.

Comment: K only appears once bud

Comment: What do you mean by $\|\cdot\|_2$? The $L^2$-norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value at 1/2 will work: consider the square root of an arbitrarily narrow "triangle function" with a fixed value at $x=1/2$. Then the $L^2$ norm will go to zero.

If you don't like piecewise functions then you can also do an example with a function that goes to zero on $(0,1]$ non-uniformly, goes to something nonzero at 0, and is uniformly bounded. There is a classic example of such a thing...

Comment: for your first example if i evaluate at 1/2 wouldn't i get a constant value there? this wouldn't proof that the equation $||Tf|| \le K||f||_2$ doesn't hold for any $K$ right?

Comment: @Rodrigo It does if $\| f \|_2$ can be made arbitrarily small, which it can.